# Как процессор работает с периферией?

Tags: книги, процессор

Ищу информацию о том, как процессор работает с винчестером, интернет-картой, как он загружает данные в память и отправляет их.
Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь книгу, или объясните кратко.

Comment: работа с периферией - это функция ОС, процессор - кусок кремния/германия

Comment: Ну допустим. Но ОС - это всего лишь набор команд, загруженных в ОЗУ. То есть, существует же какой-то набор низкоуровневых команд, которым она пользуется для взаимодействия с периферией? нет?

Comment: существует набор команд, которыми она пользуется для взаимодействия с периферией - все верно

Comment: Я об этом и спрашиваю. Как это вообще работает. Как процессор отправляет собственно данные? В регистр записывается значение, откуда брать данные и он их копирует на неткарту, которая в свою очередь из этих данных определяет, что и куда отправлять?
А если кто-то отправил ей запрос извне - прерывание? А что в случае винчестера? Там тоже какой-то микроконтроллер, который обрабатывает загруженные данные с RAM в него?

Comment: драйвера устройств это и есть эти программы

Comment: Есть устройства двух видов - умеющие использовать DMA и не умеющие. Первым процессор через порты ввода вывода (или через ввод-вывод отраженный на память) посылает команду "читай/пиши" то то через канал DMA такой то. Предварительно он так же командует DMA - возьми то что сейчас придет и положи/читай в область памяти такую то. Во втором случае все прозаичнее, процессор сам в цикле читает из определенного порта ввода вывода данные и складывает в память.

Comment: А в случае, если пришёл запрос на неткарту - она вызывает прерывание и записывает на зарезервированный сектор данные?

Comment: В интернете очень много информации по данной теме. Искать можно по ключевым словам "архитектура эвм система ввода-вывода" - лекции, книги, статьи и т.д. Тема очень обширна, начинать желательно с азов.

Comment: Нет. данные она держит в своем буфере. когда пакет полностью у нее она шлет прерывание. Драйвер, обработчик данного прерывания, настраивает DMA на нужный ему участок памяти и говорит карте "отдавай данные DMA". В любом случае доступом к памяти обладают обычно только 2 устройства: сам процессор и контроллер прямого доступа к памяти (DMA). Все остальные устройства общаются только с ними по своей шине (PCI например)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем случае периферийное устройство оформляется, как небольшой участок памяти, записывая по определенным адресам команды и параметры, читая с определенных адресов информацию о состоянии вы работаете с устройством. Бывает, что иногда эта область памяти выделяется в т.н. порты ввода/вывода, тогда чтение/запись осуществляются спец. командами, но это не меняет общей логики.

По взаимодействию с конкретным устройством надо читать описание контроллера который вас интересует, обычно это какая-то микросхема.

Это я всё описал очень упрощенно, чтобы изучать такие вещи надо предварительно почитать про аппаратные прерывания и их обработку и про прямой доступ к памяти т.н. DMA.

Ссылки по теме:
[Порт ввода-вывода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)
[Шина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80))
[Прерывание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
[Прямой доступ к памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: Да, ещё есть форум electronix.ru, там народ ближе к этой теме

Comment: То есть, когда запускается компьютер - в памяти выделяются адреса для этого устройства? А это устройство, в свою очередь, каждый такт проверяет, изменился ли какой-то байт, который отвечает за команду( в случае винчестера - r/w)?

Comment: Нет, устройства ещё на заводе запаяны, как участок памяти, но его адреса вне основного ОЗУ

Comment: Например, если мы отправили команду ReadSector с адресом, допустим - 0x10000 и место куда записать, например - 0x1000FFFF, винчестер ищет этот отрезок памяти(0x10000) и загружает его на 0x1000FFFF?

Comment: Можно же добавлять несколько винчестеров.. Или адреса для каждого SATA так же зарезервированы?

Comment: Это вы можете посмотреть в свойствах драйвера в ресурсах, например для Standard SATA AHCI Controller - I/O range, Memory range

Answer (score 7):

Процессор не работает непосредственно с периферией. Согласно [спецификации на, к примеру, Intel Core i7](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-datasheet-vol-1.html) (стр. 37-51), единственные шины, которые у него есть для связи с внешним миром — это три группы контактов: две для оперативной памяти (`DDR1_*`, `DDR2_*`) и одна для [QPI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickPath_Interconnect) (`QPI_*`).

То есть у процессора есть две абстракции — «оперативная память» (в кавычках, так как на самом деле это просто адресное пространство, которому может быть сопоставлено что угодно, не только ОЗУ) и канал для двухсторонней передачи пакетов (программисту он полезен только тем, что и по нему приходят прерывания и через него работают так называемые I/O-порты).

Все три шины идут в чипсет. Однако:

- с первыми двумя работает та часть чипсета, которая раньше называлась «северный мост». Он обрабатывает запросы процессора на чтение из и запись в «оперативную память», перенаправляя их либо на микросхемы ОЗУ, либо на южный мост в зависимости от того, куда какие физические адреса были назначены. Причём это назначение может динамически изменяться по запросу из BIOS или южного моста.
- с третьей работает «южный мост». Именно он взаимодействует с периферией, знает об IDE/SATA/PS2 и прочих интерфейсах. Ну или знает, к каким ногам чипсета подключены соответствующие микросхемы-контроллеры. Его задача — переводить электрические сигналы с аппаратных шин на язык QPI-прерываний процессора, а также обрабатывать запросы от «северного моста» на работу с зарезервированными областями памяти, перенаправляя их соответствующим устройствам.

Работу же конкретного устройства, — где оно будет использовать прерывания, а где будет отображать буферы в «оперативную память», — определяет его производитель. Именно поэтому и нужны драйвера, чтобы перевести это уникальное сочетание способов общения конкретного устройства с процессором в стандартные абстракции операционной системы, доступные другим программам («жёсткий диск», «сетевая карта» и т. д.).

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу:процессор может работать непосредственно с периферией.Вопрос только в том,как это реализовано.В любом случае,если это x86, или ARM процессор,у него есть такие инструкции IN и OUT,которые как раз предназначены для работы с периферией.В зависимости от периферии,есть шинный контроллер,или какой либо другой контроллер(северный мост,к примеру),обрабатывающий команды от CPU.Процессор получает инструкцию OUT port,AL, к примеру,и выставляет на шине адрес порта port,и дергает определенную ногу,отвечающую за ту периферию,в области адресов которой находится порт,шинный контроллер соответственно получив этот сигнал,подключает к шине соответствующее периферийное устройство.Если опустить детали, то процесс именно такой,на 99% архитектур. Так реализуется изолированный ввод/вывод.Прямой ввод/вывод проще - просто на шину параллельно цепляется периферия,которая маппится на определенны адрес, и можно просто писать любой командой для работы с память в эту периферию.